# Celery - ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to run simple Celery example: [celery-example-local-filesystem](https://github.com/mossadnik/celery-example-local-filesystem).

Here is a task module:

```
#tasks.py
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Here is a config:

```
#celeryconfig.py
"""Celery configuration using local filesystem only."""

from pathlib import Path


# paths for file backend, create folders
_root = Path(__file__).parent.resolve().joinpath('data')
#_root = Path('c:\\temp').parent.resolve().joinpath('data')
_backend_folder = _root.joinpath('results')
_backend_folder.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

_folders = {
    'data_folder_in': _root.joinpath('in'),
    'data_folder_out': _root.joinpath('in'),  # has to be the same as 'data_folder_in'
    'processed_folder': _root.joinpath('processed')
}

for fn in _folders.values():
    fn.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

# celery config
result_backend = 'file://{}'.format(str(_backend_folder))

broker_url = 'filesystem://'
broker_transport_options = {k: str(f) for k, f in _folders.items()}
task_serializer = 'json'
persist_results = True
result_serializer = 'json'
accept_content = ['json']
imports = ('tasks',)
```

and here is a main module:

```
#main.py
from celery import Celery, signature

app = Celery('tasks')
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

add = signature('tasks.add')

print('1 + 1 = {}'.format(add.delay(1, 1).get(timeout=3.)))
```

And here, when i try to run celery on windows, get an error:

```
$ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
[2021-04-03 18:16:35,578: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ValueError("Port could not be cast to integer value as '\\\\Users\\\\marci\\\\code\\\\django\\\\cellery_test\\\\data\\\\results'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 112, in start
    self.on_start()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\celery\apps\worker.py", line 136, in on_start
    self.emit_banner()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\celery\apps\worker.py", line 170, in emit_banner
    ' \n', self.startup_info(artlines=not use_image))),
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\celery\apps\worker.py", line 232, in startup_info
    results=self.app.backend.as_uri(),
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\celery\backends\base.py", line 143, in as_uri
    url = maybe_sanitize_url(self.url or '')
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\url.py", line 118, in maybe_sanitize_url
    return sanitize_url(url, mask)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\url.py", line 111, in sanitize_url
    return as_url(*_parse_url(url), sanitize=True, mask=mask)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\url.py", line 76, in url_to_parts
    parts.port,
  File "c:\python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 175, in port
    raise ValueError(message) from None
ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as '\\Users\\marci\\code\\django\\cellery_test\\data\\results'
```

It looks like some issue with path decoding. Does anyone faced with this issue? I will be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I created a `.env` file in my project folder root with the follow variables:

```
REDIS_URL=redis://127.0.0.1:6379/
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_DB=0
```

Then, make sure do you have a `redis.py` file at your project, the same folder where are the `wsgi.py` file with this:

```
import redis as r

from .settings import REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT, REDIS_DB

redis = r.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT, db=REDIS_DB)
```

On the `celery.py` file, at the same folder where are the `redis.py` and `wsgi.py` files, put a similar code how this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'your_project.settings')

app = Celery('your_project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

In the same folder yet, make sure do you have create a `__init__.py` file with:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

And in the `settings.py`, I add the code bellow:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

...

load_dotenv()

...

REDIS_URL = os.getenv('REDIS_URL')
REDIS_HOST = os.getenv('REDIS_HOST')
REDIS_PORT = os.getenv('REDIS_PORT')
REDIS_DB = os.getenv('REDIS_DB')

BROKER_URL = f'redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = BROKER_URL
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

After this, do you can deploy your project with this tutorial for example: https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/ or this other tutorial: https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/implementing-celery-using-django-for-background-task-processing/

I hope help you.

Answer (score 4):

The problem for me was the usage of special characters(`/`, `?`, `#`, `@` and `:`) in the url I passed to `urllib.parse`.
Once I removed them from the path, it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check whether the result backend URL is correct (check the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme for more information). I had no idea `filesystem://` is a possible broker alternative. Even if it is, it is most likely **highly experimental**, so I recommend not using it until it reaches maturity (which I sincerely doubt will ever happen, as I really do not see the point - Celery is supposed to be a DISTRIBUTED system, so filesystem as broker makes no sense to me). Please use brokers listed here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/brokers/index.html or do not use Celery at all if you have hard requirement to use something that is not on that list.